# Node app.get not found when trying to make a post request towards it, but works in browser

Tags: jquery, node.js, post

I created an API for logins in Nodejs. When i try to make a jquery post request for it, it says 404 Not found, but when i open the same page in the browser, it finds the file.

My code to request:

```
$.post("http://localhost:8000/api/login", {"username": "username", "password": "password"}, function(response) {

    console.log(response);

});
```

My code for the API (simplified):

```
app.get("/api/login", function(req, res) {

  var username = req.body.username,
  password = req.body.password;

  //login chechks but basically this is what it returns

  res.send({

    "error": 0,
    "loggedIn": 1

  });
  res.end();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app.get` creates a route that accepts GET requests.
change it to `app.post` to accept POST requests.

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.get.method